# Accessing sql server 2008 analysis service database on cmd

Tags: sql-server

I have currently installed SQL server without the management studio but now I want to delete a database on the analysis service but I cannot after installing the management studio because I cannot see the analysis service on the connect to tab. Is there anyway I can access the services from command prompt and delete the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ascmd - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365187(v=sql.90).aspx